# Flutter show Image picker when the image itself is clicked?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I am using the image_picker package and my code is as simple as :

**The ImagePicker and the image itself : **

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            getImage();
          },
          child: Container(
            child: pickedImagePath == null
                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/profilePhotoAvatar.svg',
                    height: size.height * 0.15,
                  )
                : Image.file(
                    File(pickedImagePath!.path),
                    height: size.height * 0.15,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
```

**The Getimage function :**

```
 XFile? pickedImagePath;

Future<void> getImage() async {
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    pickedImagePath = pickedImage;
  });
}
```

I am using a stateful widget, the plugin is properly set, I am able to pick and image from gallery  and The pickedimage path does update if I try a print, It's just that the image won't update on this code

```
pickedImagePath == null
                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/profilePhotoAvatar.svg',
                    height: size.height * 0.15,
                  )
                : Image.file(
                    File(pickedImagePath!.path),
                    height: size.height * 0.15,
                  ),
```

Thanks in advance for anybody who can help

Comment: Is an error being thrown in the console when the image should update? This could be caused by the Image widget not working with XFile

Comment: Sometimes i see people define variables and methods inside the build method. This would set pickedImagePath back to null, can you check it?

Comment: What is the value for `size.height`?

Comment: make sure to declare variable outside the build method

Comment: @targiasld so many times I learn the same lesson and can't get rid of this habbit. Thanks, That's what was going on here